# Istio Tracing Issues

Tags: trace, zipkin, istio

I have made a trivial 3 tier services similar to the bookinfo app on the Istio site. Everything seems to work fine, except for the tracing with zipkin or jaeger.

To clarify, I have 3 services S1, S2, S3, all pretty similar and trivial passing requests downstream and doing some work. I can see S1 and S2 in the trace, but not S3.  I have narrowed this down a bit further, when i use Istio version 0.5.0, I can see S3 in the trace as well, but only after some time, however, with Istio version 0.5.1, I can only see S1 and S2 in the trace, even though the services are working properly and the calls are propagating down all the way to S3.

The only difference that I can see, which I am not sure if this is even an issue or not, is this output in istio-proxy for S3 using istio version 0.5.0, but not in 0.5.1

"GET /readiness HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0 39 1 1 "-" "kube-probe/1.9+" "0969a5a3-f6c0-9f8e-a449-d8617c3a5f9f" "10.X.X.18:8080" "127.0.0.1:8080"

I can add the exact yaml files if need. Also, I am not sure if the tracing is supposed to be coming from istio-proxy as it shows in the istio docs, but in my case, I do not see istio-proxy but rather istio-ingress only.

Answer (score 0):

Trace context propagation might be missing.

https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/overview/#trace-context-propagation

```
Although Istio proxies are able to automatically send spans, they need some hints to tie together the entire trace. Applications need to propagate the appropriate HTTP headers so that when the proxies send span information, the spans can be correlated correctly into a single trace.

To do this, an application needs to collect and propagate the following headers from the incoming request to any outgoing requests:

x-request-id
x-b3-traceid
x-b3-spanid
x-b3-parentspanid
x-b3-sampled
x-b3-flags
x-ot-span-context

Additionally, tracing integrations based on OpenCensus (e.g. Stackdriver) propagate the following headers:

x-cloud-trace-context
traceparent
grpc-trace-bin
```